# AngularJS 1.5.5 Directive: $element.find() / $element.children() does not always work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-1.5

This is a sample directive I have created to help understand the issue described in the title:

```
define(['angular'], function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  var randomElement = angular.module('RandomElement', []);

  randomElement.directive('randomElement', function() { return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: false,
    template: '<div><span class="random-span"></span></div>',
    controller: function($scope, $element) {

      // This method is triggered in a ng-click binding
      $scope.findSpan = function() {
        // About 20-30% of page reloads, this returns 0 results
        console.log($element.find('.random-span'));
      }

    }
  }});

  return randomElement;
});
```

Note the `$scope.findSpan` method. That's the problem I am having: about 20-30% of page reloads, the `$element.find()` (or `$element.children()` for that matter) return 0 results.

Is there a known cause for the problem I am experiencing? Is there a solid solution for passing a reference to the sub-element defined in the template to the scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was a race condition between loading `jqLite` and `jQuery`. If jQuery loaded fast enough, jQuery was used instead of jqLite and the statement worked. With only jqLite, the statement failed.

The solution, for RequireJS, was to add `jQuery` as an `Angular` dependency in the entry file.